# Two types of Chinese unicode characters are in a Microsoft SQL database and display on a page, but only one type will display correctly at a time

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, asp-classic

Sorry, this is going to take some typing to explain what is going on, but I believe I have a very specific problem here and I've been struggling with it for a long time.

There are two ways that Unicode (specifically, Chinese) characters are getting entered into my Microsoft SQL Server database:

1. A user located in Taiwan is typing directly into a web form on a Windows computer that has Chinese as its default language, then my ASP script writes the result to the database.
2. A user located in the U.S. on a Macintosh has an Excel spreadsheet of language translations, which gets saved to a CSV file, uploaded to the server, then an ASP script processes that file and writes to the database. The actual characters in the Excel file come from a variety of sources: via e-mail from Taiwan, a Word or Excel file from Taiwan, or sometimes from Google Translate (via the web).

When I read from the database and display the text on a web page, here is what happens:

Using ASP, I insert this code at the top of my page:

```
response.CharSet="UTF-8"
```

In the `<head>` area of the page, I also insert this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

With only that, here is my test page:
https://www.interactivehealthpartner.com/test-4.asp

The text from the U.S. computer is just question marks, the text from the Taiwan computer looks fine.

Next, I try adding another line of ASP code at the top of my page:

```
response.CodePage=65001
```

Here is the result:
https://www.interactivehealthpartner.com/test-3.asp

Now, the text from the U.S. computer looks fine, but the text from the the Taiwan computer is garbage.

From what I understand, `response.CodePage=65001` is the same thing as UTF-8.

When I try selecting the text via a SQL Server Management Studio query window directly, I see the U.S. computer text looks fine, but the Taiwan computer text is garbage.

At this point, I am lost. I need to get a web page to display both of these types of text correctly, on the same page.

My assumption is that there is some difference between the character set on the U.S. computer vs. the Taiwan computer… that even though they are both Chinese, they are different versions of Chinese? If the data were exactly the same type, they should display the same on a web page.

Also, why adding `response.CodePage=65001` flip-flops the success of those two types of text is a mystery to me.

Note that when the U.S. text goes bad, its all question marks. When the Taiwan text goes bad, its garbage characters.

Would really appreciate any insight to this. Thank you!

Comment: Try to narrow the problem down. Start looking directly at the database. Are the two types of characters stored in the same type of nvarchar column? Select a representative string of each type in SQL Mgmt Studio and look at the bytes. Are they encoded differently?

Comment: Are your web pages saved as UTF-8?  (You'll see the option if you select "save as" from the file menu in Notepad.)  Is your CSV file also saved as UTF8.  If all your input pages/files use UTF-8 then you should get UTF-8 out.  This is a useful page for background reading.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Comment: Also, reading your question again, the funny characters you see are closer to where you want to be than the question marks. Is your <%@language="vscript" codepage="65001"%> declaration on your results page only, or have you also added it to your input form page?

Comment: Thanks for all the input. (@acfrancis) Regarding the database, yes they are both nvarchar columns. I created them both the same way, they are different lengths, but otherwise identical (I checked their properties list in Design view). However, I'm not sure how to "look at the bytes" of strings selected in Management Studio to see if they are encoded differently. Are you able to tell me how to do that?

Comment: (@John) Yes, I thought that was the case, that the funny characters are "closer" to correct than the question marks. So correcting that is probably the way to go, rather than the other way around. The page that has the input form does not have any codepage setting, only the meta tag charset for UTF-8. The codepage ASP code is on the results page only (linked in my question).

Comment: (@John) The web pages (ASP scripts) themselves are not UTF-8, they are plain text. But the ASP code in them pulls the UTF-8 data from the database and writes it to the page.

Comment: In that case give ALL your asp pages the codepage="65001" declaration I suggested above, and if they contain any HTML make sure they have meta tags to declare the charset as UTF-8.  If they have any hard coded Chinese characters save them with an editor which lets you specifically select the coding in the Save As screen. (Plain Notepad will do).  This is essentially what is suggested in the Scott Hanselman blog I linked to.  Once you've done all this try entering Chinese again through via webform from your Taiwan based computer and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I finally figured out the problem… UTF-8 using a form with enctype="multipart/form-data" and ASPupload (Persits Software). It garbles the unicode. I had to add a line of code (provided by Persits) and now it appears to work fine.